# Moving node Div Up and Down using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering is there a way in Javascript to just move node div element up and down without id. When the item is selected and right clicked then there would be Move Up and Move Down option,now on Move Up click it should Move Up in div.

For example..

```
<div>
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>

        </div>
```

Suppose i right clicked on div 3, then Move Up option will be there so on click of Move Up it should Move Up and new sequence should be

```
 <div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>

    </div>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: what you have tried yet.

Comment: I am new to Javascript, so any help to start up would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: I have posted the answer as per your requirement. [Code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22602526/3129183)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is some example. Try  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sjnilan/ahj4J/104/).

Click on the Item to select it.

```
<div id='items'>
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>

        </div>

<a href="#" id="up">Up</a>
<a href="#" id="down">Down</a>
```

**Jquery library**

Add this library to your page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js'></script>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selected=0;

     var itemlist = $('#items');
    var len=$(itemlist).children().length; 

    $("#items div").click(function(){
        selected= $(this).index();
        alert("Selected item is " + $(this).text());
    });


     $("#up").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       if(selected>0)
        {
            jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected-1)).before(jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected)));
            selected=selected-1;
        }
    });

     $("#down").click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
        if(selected < len)
        {
            jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected+1)).after(jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected)));
            selected=selected+1;
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code. Right Click on the list item and move it up or down.
**HTML**

```
<div class="block">
  <div>
    <div class="contextMenu">
        <ul>
            <li data-sort="up">Up</li>
            <li data-sort="down">Down</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    1</div>
  <div>
    <div class="contextMenu">
        <ul>
            <li data-sort="up">Up</li>
            <li data-sort="down">Down</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  2</div>
  <div>
    <div class="contextMenu">
        <ul>
            <li data-sort="up">Up</li>
            <li data-sort="down">Down</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  3</div>
  <div>
    <div class="contextMenu">
        <ul>
            <li data-sort="up">Up</li>
            <li data-sort="down">Down</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  4</div>
  <div>
    <div class="contextMenu test">
        <ul>
            <li data-sort="up">Up</li>
            <li data-sort="down">Down</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  5</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.block {width:300px;}
.block > div { border:1px solid #e5e5e5; position:relative;}
.contextMenu{ position:absolute; font-size:11px; width:50px; background:#e5e5e5; z-index:999; display:none;}
.contextMenu ul{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
.contextMenu li{border:1px solid #666; padding:5px;}
```

**Script**

```
$('.block > div').mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 ){
        $(this).find('.contextMenu').show().end().siblings('div').find('.contextMenu').hide();
    };
})

$('.contextMenu li').on('click', function(){
        var parentDiv = $(this).closest('div.contextMenu').parent(),
            dir = $(this).data('sort');

    if(dir === 'up'){
        parentDiv.insertBefore( parentDiv.prev() )
    } else if(dir === 'down'){
        parentDiv.insertAfter( parentDiv.next() )
    }
    $('.contextMenu').hide()
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Fdux/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there a way instead of writing context menu in every div, we can write it as separate function and just call it on div on which we want context menu to appear??? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simplest Solution with **Vanilla (Plain) JavaScript**

```js
const moveUp = (element) => {
  if(element.previousElementSibling)
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(element, element.previousElementSibling);
}
const moveDown = (element) => {
  if(element.nextElementSibling)
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(element.nextElementSibling, element);
}
```

```css
.up, .down {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div id="a"> 
  <strong>Section A</strong>
  <span onclick="moveUp(a)" class="up">^</span>
  <span onclick="moveDown(a)" class="down">v</span>
</div>

<div id="b">
  <strong>Section B</strong>
  <span onclick="moveUp(b)" class="up">^</span>
  <span onclick="moveDown(b)" class="down">v</span>
</div>

<div id="c">
  <strong>Section C</strong>
  <span onclick="moveUp(c)" class="up">^</span>
  <span onclick="moveDown(c)" class="down">v</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you want as an answer, but looking at what you want to achieve, you can use [jQuery UI Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/)

`example here` :[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Fdux/)

Comment: Well that is just drag and drop, i want div to move up on click of MOVE UP option in context menu. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#downButton").click(function() {
    var selectedRows = $('#tblValues tr').find("td:first").find("input:checked").parents('tr');
    $(selectedRows).each(function(index, item) {
        $(item).insertAfter($(item).next());
    });
});
```