# moving node div with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have a lists of html div and i want to arranged/sort it by drag and drop using jquery/javascript. This is my html to be drag and drop.

```
<div id="wrap">
 <div>
  <input type="text" name="qs1-type" value="Hi1">
   ....
 </div>
 <div>
  <input type="radio" name="qs2-type" value="True">
  <input type="radio" name="qs2-type" value="False">
   ....
 </div>
 <div>
  <input type="text" name="qs3-type1" value="OKs">
  <input type="text" name="qs3-type2" value="Number">
   ....
 </div>
...
 <div>
  <input type="text" name="qs8-type" value="Bolder">
   ....
 </div>
 <div>
  <textarea name="qs9-type"> some text</textarea>
   ....
 </div>
</div>
```

right now I based my code here : [Moving node Div Up and Down using Javascript/Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601672/moving-node-div-up-and-down-using-javascript-jquery)

but I want it to be drag and undroppable.. any idea? I have search in the internet bt no luck for having same issues as I do.

Comment: Jquery ui can do this https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

Comment: thanks vbranden.. it works well