# how to put auto value to element with same class, counting value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html element with same class with different values.

```
<div>
<p>1</p>
<input type="hidden" name="qs-ordered[]" class="qs_cntss" value="0">
</div>
<div>
<p>2</p>
<input type="hidden" name="qs-ordered[]" class="qs_cntss" value="0">
</div>
<div>
<p>3</p>
<input type="hidden" name="qs-ordered[]" class="qs_cntss" value="0">
</div>
<div>
<p>4</p>
<input type="hidden" name="qs-ordered[]" class="qs_cntss" value="0">
</div>
...
<div>
<p>7</p>
<input type="hidden" name="qs-ordered[]" class="qs_cntss" value="0">
</div>
```

now I want to re assign its value by counting its number when calls a function. This is my current code:

```
jQuery("div").click(function(){
        var cnt = 1;
        jQuery('.qs_cntss').each(function(){
            jQuery('.qs_cntss').val(cnt);
            cnt++;
        });
    });


jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "div" ).sortable({
      revert: true
    });
    jQuery( "div" ).disableSelection();
  });
```

but the issues all the `.qs_cntss` value were all `7`.. but I want it to be that the first order will be: 1,2,3,4..7... like

```
<div>
<p>1</p>
<input type="hidden" name="qs-ordered[]" class="qs_cntss" value="1">
</div>
<div>
<p>2</p>
<input type="hidden" name="qs-ordered[]" class="qs_cntss" value="2">
</div>
<div>
<p>3</p>
<input type="hidden" name="qs-ordered[]" class="qs_cntss" value="3">
</div>
<div>
<p>4</p>
<input type="hidden" name="qs-ordered[]" class="qs_cntss" value="4">
</div>
...
<div>
<p>7</p>
<input type="hidden" name="qs-ordered[]" class="qs_cntss" value="7">
</div>
```

I got this idea because I want it to apply with this [Moving node Div Up and Down using Javascript/Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601672/moving-node-div-up-and-down-using-javascript-jquery) and https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable .. so whenever I drag a div, it changes the all `qs_cntss` values, according to its order.. is it possible?

Comment: Is expected result that `value` of elements be incremented at each `click` event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why all are 7 is you set `jQuery('.qs_cntss').val(cnt);`.

try using `this`:-

```
   jQuery("div").click(function(){
        var cnt = 1;
        jQuery('.qs_cntss').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).val(cnt);
            cnt++;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line of code:

```
jQuery('.qs_cntss').val(cnt);
```

You execute this in each iteration of your loop.  Remember that the selector `.qs_cntss` targets *all* elements that have this class, thus it makes sense for all elements to be set to 7 after the loop is complete.  To fix this problem, simply replace it with `this`.

```
jQuery(this).val(cnt);
```